# Avoid HTTP 302 response code when setting the Location header in PHP after POST

Tags: php, http, post, http-headers, httpresponse

I need to put a `201 Created` Response code and a Location header for a POST request, but for some reason I am still getting a 302 response.

This is what I have:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 201');
header("Location: ..."); // The new resource URL
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $response;
exit;
```

I have tried removing the content type, the `echo` and the `exit` without any luck, still getting the 302. I read that I need to specify both headers, but that's what I am doing and no luck. I also tried with:

```
header("Location: ...", TRUE, 201);
```

Nothing, still got 302 :(

Does anybody knows what I am not seeing?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is 302 inappropriate in your case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the order around:

```
header("Location: ..."); // The new resource URL
header('HTTP/1.1 201 Created');
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $response;
exit;
```

Test:

```
# curl -i "http://localhost/projects/scratch/302.php"
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Sun, 29 Jan 2012 23:09:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5
Location: ...
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

#### Another way

Keep the original order, but force a 201. [According to the PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set.

```
header('HTTP/1.1 201 Created', true, 201);
header("Location: ..."); // The new resource URL
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $response;
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still got a 302 :(

Comment: The method you mentioned in your OP and this method both work for me. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: `header('HTTP/1.1 201');` should be `header('HTTP/1.1 201 Created');` - the response must have both a numerical code and a (matching) textual description, as per RFC2616: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1

Comment: Thank you very much for the alternatives, but I'm still getting a 302.

Comment: @Alec, I never solved this issue :S I don't remember what did I ended up doing, but anyway, new customer needs eliminated the need for that code. I will still accept your answer, thanks for your time :)