# Header in PHP overrides the HTTP Response code

Tags: php, apache, http, http-headers

Working around setting rules at Apache level, Found that header('Location: filename.php') in php overrides the response code. Look at the below code :-

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect'); //or Try for 4xx/5xx Code
header('Location: http://hello.php');
?>
```

`Expected result`

- HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
- Host: localhost:8000
- Location: hello.php
- Connection: close
- X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.6

`Actual result`

- HTTP/1.1 `302 Found`
- Host: localhost:8000
- Location: hello.php
- Connection: close
- X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.6

Is something wrong at Apache level or its Bug in PHP ?

Update:[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: I think that it is neither of it. Where do you look for the header result.

Comment: I didn't get any warnings. I saw the result in Firebug as well as in HTTPFox(addons).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid HTTP 302 response code when setting the Location header in PHP after POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057587/avoid-http-302-response-code-when-setting-the-location-header-in-php-after-post)

Comment: @CodeCaster its not duplicate brother.Its overrides the header to 302 in 308,300, any 4.x.x and 5.x.x even.

Comment: It is exactly the same, regardless the status code you wish to return. Read the question and accepted answer.

Comment: Why the downvote ? Apart from Question and Answer in which they talking about order of headers, the only useful line is "it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set."

Comment: Try Setting header('HTTP/1.1 300 Permanent Redirect');  OR header('HTTP/1.1 401 Permanent Redirect'); OR header('HTTP/1.1 500 Permanent Redirect'); , in all cases it returning 302 Resp code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the function documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) this is the desired behaviour of PHP when sending the Location header.

EDIT: Sorry, misread your message. It will override the response code if you send a code different than 3xx, so it should work with a 308.
Are you sure that no other HTTP code is sent back ? Does your client tries to retrieve the new resource and you see the 302 as a final result ?

FINAL EDIT: Did you try

```
header('Location: /some/page.php', TRUE, 308);
```

Comment: header('Location: /some/page.php', TRUE, 308); worked perfectly in php 5.5.9

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [PHP documentation of header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), there is a special case for "Location" type of header. It sets 302 response code **unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set** . Unfortunately it doesn't work as you can see on your example.

I've played with code and looks like it works when you change the order of operations like this:

```
<?php
header('Location: landing.php');
header('HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect');
?>
```

It seems that **header('Location ...** overrides the response code in any case but doing **header('HTTP/1.1 308...** after it change it back to 308.

Did some extra investigations and here is the result.

```
header('Location: http://smth');
```

doesn't change the response code for 3** except 308. So if you do

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect');
header('Location: landing.php');
?>
```

the code above will work ok as expected. 
So you're 'lucky' to find exception in the rule. While my workaround allows to solve the issue.
PS: Using PHP 5.4.27